# Grunt select all files of a certain filetype

Tags: gruntjs

How do I select all files of a certain file type? Like so;

```
src: '**/*.(js|rb|html|...)'
```

Is there a way of doing this, or do I have to make an array `['**/*.js', '**/*.rb', '**/*.html', ...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply a *extglob*:

```
**/*.+(js|rb|html)
```

This is mentioned in the documentation of [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) (used by Grunt).